# Extracting elements from list using Python

Tags: python-2.7, spyder

How can I extract `'1' '11'` and `'111'` from this list ?

```
T0 = ['4\t1\t\n', '0.25\t11\t\n', '0.2\t111\t\n']
```

to extract `'4'`, `'0.25'` and `'0.2'` I used this :

```
def extract(T0):
    T1 = []
for i in range(0, len(T0)):
    pos = T0[i].index('\t')
T1.append(resultat[i][0: pos])
return T1
```

then I got :

```
T1 = ['4','0.25','0.2']
```

but for the rest I don't know how to extract it
can you help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your code as base, it can be done as below. Will return as string if its alphabet, otherwise return as decimal integer.

```
def extract(T0): 
    T1=[] 
    for i in range len(T0):
        tmp = T0[i].split('\t')[1]
        if tmp.isalpha():
            T1.append(tmp)
        else:
            T1.append(int(tmp))
    return T1
```

Alternatively, try below for a more compact code using list comprehension

```
def extract(T0):
    # return as string if its alphabet else return as decimal integer
    # change int function to float if wanna return as float
    tmp = [i.split('\t')[1] for i in T0]
    return [i if i.isalpha() else int(i) for i in tmp]
```

Example

```
T0= ['X\tY\tf(x.y)\n', '0\t0\t\n', '0.1\t10\t\n', '0.2\t20\t\n', '0.3\t30\t\n']
extract(T0) # return ['Y', 0, 10, 20, 30]
```

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate your help

Comment: then, to convert each one of these elements to numerical value, which function shall I use please?

Comment: You could use int function to convert string to integer and float function to convert string into float. Already edit my answer to include that

Comment: it doesn't work because my list contain 'Y' at th beginning: ['Y', '0', '10', '20', '30', '40', '50', '60', '70', '80', '90', '100']

Comment: So you want return as string if non numeric and return as integer if its numeric ? Like above shall return as ['Y', 0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90] ?

Comment: in fact I have to convert all the other elements excpet the first (I should not delete the 'Y')

Comment: yes that's it, I want return as string if non numeric and return as integer if its numeric

Comment: no, it doesn't work
to better understand you can run this if you want: 

T0= ['X\tY\tf(x.y)\n', '0\t0\t\n', '0.1\t10\t\n', '0.2\t20\t\n', '0.3\t30\t\n']

def extractY(T0):
    TY=[]
    for i in range (0,len(T0)):
        TY.append(T0[i].split('\t')[1])  
    return TY 
print (extractY(T0))

Comment: Great, You could show your thanks better by accept the answer, there is big check box at the left of the answer. Or vote the answer useful :)

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with the `re` module and a list comprehension.

```
import re

# create a regular expression object
regex = re.compile(r'[0-9]{1,}\.{0,1}[0-9]{0,}') 

# assign the input list
T0 = ['4\t1\t\n', '0.25\t11\t\n', '0.2\t111\t\n']

# get a list of extractions using the regex
extractions = [x for x in [re.findall(regex, e) for e in T0]]

print extractions
# => [['4', '1'], ['0.25', '11'], ['0.2', '111']]
```